# Am I using gcc wrong?

Tags: c++, gcc

I've been having no end of trouble just getting started with C++. Seems like no matter what I do, I've got dozens of errors. I've taken to compiling example code from tutorials, but even the example code doesn't compile. For example, the code at:
http://www.cppgameprogramming.com/cgi/nav.cgi?page=arrayclasses

gives me lots of flack when I try to:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o dog
```

It says:

```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:18:15: warning: deleting
> array 'Dog myDogs [5]'
> C:\Users\bob-pc\Appdata\Local\Temp\ccTXXCOB.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x21):
> undefined rference to 'Dog::Dog()' C:\Users\bob-pc\Appdata\Local\Temp\ccTXXCOB.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x59):
> undefined rference to 'Dog::setAge(int)' C:\Users\bob-pc\Appdata\Local\Temp\ccTXXCOB.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x88):
> undefined rference to 'Dog::getAge()' collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

This isn't the first time I've tried straight copying example code & compiling it. I'm having lots of trouble even after I go over syntax, but I just can't seem to get headers & libraries working right. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If you're just getting started with C++, please get [a proper introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It'll cover issues like this and much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include `dog.cpp` in the compilation:

```
g++ main.cpp dog.cpp -o dog
```

Alternatively, you can compile `dog.cpp` by itself to an object file, and include that in the final compilation:

```
g++ dog.cpp -c -o dog.o

g++ main.cpp dog.o -o dog
```

Comment: Thank you! I still get an error of:main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:18:15: warning: deleting array 'Dog myDogs [5]' Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jackalope: The code on that webpage is flat out wrong. You `delete[]` only when you use `new[]`. The declaration `Dog myDogs[5];` allocates an array of 5 `Dog`s on automatic storage. You don't need to call `delete[]` on arrays allocated on automatic storage; it'll be destroyed automatically at the end of the scope (in this case, the `main()` function).

Comment: @Jackalope This is terrible code, and you shouldn't be trying to learn *anything* from this website. Delete the line `delete [] myDogs;` Also warnings aren't "errors". Your program is successfully compiling, but the compiler is warning you that there could be trouble with some of your code.

Comment: @meagar: True, but one should still strive to compile as cleanly as possible (no warnings, errors, etc).

Comment: @Jackalope: Like I said, please pick up [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I wouldn't use code from a website that demonstrates no understanding of array memory management.

Comment: @Jackalope: Unfortunately and coincidentally, game programmers *tend* to be some of the worse programmers I've ever seen, hands down.

Comment: Thanks, all of you, for your advice! I think I'll pick up a good book as you advise.

Answer (score 4):

The example code is just plain wrong. :-)

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Dog.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Dog myDogs[5];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        myDogs[i].setAge( i * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        cout << "Dog number " << i << " is " << myDogs[i].getAge() << " years old!\n";

    delete [] myDogs;    <--- Don't do this!

    return 0;
}
```

You should not use `delete` if you have not used `new` to allocate the object. It this case the dogs will take care of themselves. Just remove the line with `delete`!

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to determine what is going on without taking a look at your code. Make sure you're including the .o of the file where the class dog is defined.

Also if the array wasn't created with new[], don't use delete[].

Finally, I know you're not specifically asking about this, but it may be worth it to find a better resource online to learn C++. At least use one that doesn't have embarrassing mistakes.

Comment: More precisely, if the array wasn't allocated with `new[]`, don't use `delete[]`.  In this case the array wasn't statically defined (it has automatic storage duration), but the `delete[]` is definitely wrong (it's likely to corrupt the program's internal memory management system).